# Copy an Array - Bad Design?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I learn objective-C from Stanford iTunes and i wonder how i should copy a NSMutableArray to NSArray without initialization. I mean:

Is this is correct? with "lazy initialization".

```
-(void)copyAnArray:(NSMutableArray*)listOfElements {
    if(privateElementsLists == nil)
        privateElementsLists = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:listOfElements copyItems:YES];
    else
        privateElementsLists = listOfElements;
}
```

is this a bad design?
I want to addobjects to mutable array in one class, and then when i'm finish copy entire NSMutableArray to NSArray.

And another question: Why i have to use `copyItems:YES` when I use initWithArray? And what's deep copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a mutable array to a new array with initWithArray: or this way:

```
privateElementsLists = [NSArray arrayWithArray:listOfElements];
```

then you are creating a new array where each of its elements is the same object that figures in the original array. If you write:

```
privateElementsLists = [NSArray arrayWithArray:listOfElements copyItems:YES];
```

then the new array have, for each element, a copy of the element in original array. They are not the same object but a copy. Of course, that objects have to be able to respond to copy.

You can even do this:

```
privateElementsLists = (NSArray*) listOfElements ;
```

Then the array is exactly the same as the original one. No new array here. But as you have casted it with NSArray pointer class, you can use it as if it is a NSArray instead of a NSMutableArray. As you know, every NSMutableArray is a NSArray (inherited class).

Comment: +1 for the thoroughness.  However, you don't need to do the cast in the last statement. An NSMutableArray is always an NSArray, so no cast is needed.  If you were reversing the order (assigning an NSArray to an NSMutableArray) then the cast would be needed as there is no guarantee the NSArray is actually an NSMutable Array.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand the mechanisms. But still have a question: I should have my data in NSArray after collecting them, or leave it in NSMutableArray?

Comment: @Joseph, I know I don't have to, but for this explanation I think it is clearer.
For SimpleMan, do what you need to do. You can use the mutable array because it is an array. You don't have to build another one if there are not a good reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Joseph DeCarlo stated, you don't need to copy `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` if the only thing you do is to create the array in one place to use it somewhere else. For example this statement is valid:

```
NSArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Or in the code:

```
-(NSArray*)returnAnArray
{
    NSMutableArray* editableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [editableArray addObject:[[NSObject alloc] init]]; //an exemplary object added to the array
    return editableArray;
}
```

That said, however, in some specific cases casting `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` may not be safe, e.g. if the original array was stored in an instance variable. Adding or removing objects to/from that array may cause a crash if the returned array is enumerated at the same time. For example:

```
-(void)createArray
{
    self->editableArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // instance variable: NSMutableArray* editableArray
}

-(void)addObjectToArray
{
    [self->editableArray addObject:[[NSObject alloc] init]];
}

-(NSArray*)getArray
{
    return self->editableArray;
}

-(void)enumerateArray
{
    for(NSObject obj in [self getArray])
    {
        // do something with obj
    }
}
```

If `addObjectToArray` is called at the same time as `enumerateArray` (e.g. from a background thread) the application will crash because the underlying array is changing while it is being enumerated. It doesn't matter that it was returned as `NSArray*`. In a case like this you would need to either add `@synchronized` to synchronize access to the same object by multiple threads, or copy the entire array with `arrayWithArray:` as suggested. Note, however, that the documentation doesn't say if `arrayWithArray:` is thread safe so I would add `@synchronized` around the call to `arrayWithArray:` anyway.

Comment: Thanks! That's explain a lot!